# On generalised coordinates of scleronomic systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, constrained-dynamics

Do scleronomic constraints and [scleronomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scleronomous) systems mean the same? Also, are the [generalised coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) of a scleronomic system explicitly independent of time?

Comment: Doesn't the wikipedia you linked to kind of answer your first question?

Comment: @NDewolf,yes,but I was more confused about the second part , so I wanted to tag along the 1st question in hope of a differently approached answer!